# Можно ли найти средствами php номер автомобиля на картинке и зарисовать его?

Tags: php

Можно ли найти средствами php номер автомобиля на картинке и зарисовать его?

Comment: ну вообще можно, с использованием `opencv`. Можно и без. но если без, то тут уже гуглите работы по работе с изображениями.

Comment: Используйте нейросети